# Open a context window from a calculated column?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

I have a workflow sending tasks from multiple lists to a "task overview" list.

Users can edit a task directly from the "receiving" overview list by clicking a URL button which opens up the corresponding task from the "sending" task list in a new tab of the web browser.  I can also make it replace the page in the current tab by taking "Target='_blank'" out of the calculation.

I'm using the formula below in a calculated column.   Is there a way to modify it to open the sending list's task context window in a frame overlaying the existing page (pop-up window) instead of appearing in a new tab or replacing the page in the current tab?

`=IF(ISBLANK(SendingURL),"URL Missing",("<a href="&SendingURL&" target='_blank' alt='Open site in new window'><img src='https://whatever.org/PublishingImages/Icon.png' style='height:20px; width:20px;' /></a>"))`

Comment: It should already work. What are you seeing?

Comment: With the _blank it opens in a new tab.  If I remove it it opens in the current window.  It isn't worded well in the question, I'll change that in a minute.  The "context" window will open in a new window or in the existing window depending on whether or not the "_blank" exists in the formula.   I would like it to pop up in a frame, overlaying the existing window.

Answer (score 0):

If tabs will not work for you, you will need to use js `window.open()` to achieve opening it in the new window. The new window will not overlay the existing window in that case though.

For additional information, review:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12939928/make-a-link-open-a-new-window-not-tab